# How to Create HTML table with fixed header but dynamic column

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, html-table

I have two HTML buttons, one named 3days and other named week. Based on the click of any of these buttons I need to create a dynamic table with Fixed Headers but dynamic column. For example, suppose I clicked on 3days button,then the resultant table should be with 2 fixed headers and 3 dynamic column with 1,2,3 as name of the column. LIkewise if clicked on week button then HTML table should be with 2 fixed headers and 7 columns with column name as 1,2,3,4,5,6.

I have a HTML table but how to create it dynamically using ajax and jQuery? I am not getting that.

HTML table..

```
 <div id="table">
    <table style="height:500px">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Please help me to resolve this..

Comment: How you are formatting table, please give real example instead column1 ,2..

Comment: @mrdeveloper Column names are meant for dd from dd/mm/yy datetype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column A</th>
                <th id="flex-header">Column B</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<button value="3">3</button>
<button value="7">7</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        var cols = $(this).val();

        // You'll want to do something here to get the column data
        var data = $("<tr></tr>").append($("<td>Col 0</td>"));
        for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            data.append($("<td>Col " + (i + 1) + "</td>"));
        }
        $("#flex-header").prop("colspan", cols);
        $("#table table tbody").html("").append(data);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_tesh/7AXps/)

This will allow you to change around the number of columns easily. Of course, there are other ways to do it (like the other answer with toggling tbody elements) but this should give you a little flexibility with the column counts.

**EDIT**
Here is an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_tesh/7AXps/1/) with the table toggle behavior.

Comment: Sir i need columns also to get added for example if its 3day then 3 columns and like that ...and i need table on button click evcent onl;y

Comment: I get the feeling that you are looking for me to do this for you, and that is not going to happen. I have given you a starting point, so have at it. Good luck to you...

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Code:**

```
   $("table").hide();
$("#3").click(function(){
    $("table").show();
    $("th:gt(2)").hide();  
    $("td:gt(2)").hide();  
});

$("#7").click(function(){
     $("table").show();
    $("th:lt(7)").show();  
    $("td:lt(7)").show();  
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/3kUjR/2/

Comment: At present table cells are getting added whereas i need table columns